# WTForms l10n and i18n not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm learning to use flask. I can't make WTForms built-in translations work

http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html#using-the-built-in-translations-provider

Here is my Form class

```
class MyBaseForm(Form):
class Meta:
    locales = ['es_ES', 'es']

class LoginAdminForm(MyBaseForm):
    user = StringField('user', validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
    password = StringField('password', validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
```

Here is the routing

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

@app.route('/admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adminLogin():
    form = LoginAdminForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/index') #TODO: Redirect to actual admin menu
    return render_template("adminLogin.html", title="Admin login",form=form)
```

Here is the config

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
SECRET_KEY = 'you-will-never-guess'
```

Here is the adminLogin.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <form action="" method="post" name="login">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
      Usuario:
      {{ form.user }}
      {% for error in form.password.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}<br>
      Ingrese Contraseña:
      {{ form.password }}
      {% for error in form.password.errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
      {% endfor %}<br>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Acceder"></p>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html is just an empty html skeleton
Errors always come out in english. I also tried passing the parameter in the constructor didn't work either

```
form = LoginAdminForm(meta={'locales': ['en_US', 'en']})
```

EDIT: After a while of playing around i ditched flask-WTForm and went with pure WTForms. And then it worked. I'm guessing it's a bug on flask-WTForm. If i don't get an answer I'll go with pure WTForms

Answer (score 0):

The method i was using worked but only with WTForm NOT with flask-WTForm. I'm assuming it's a bug. I couldn't find any documentation about it.
I'll be using pure WTForm now since it seems to fix the problem.

Comment: I opened a ticket about this bug, this is not fixed at the moment.
https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/issues/582